# How to create a Mono build server on Linux (Jenkins on Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, build, mono, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to set up a build server for a Mono project on Ubuntu.

The motivation is to have my C# projects for .NET built to run on Linux hosts. So I want to develop on Windows/Linux, commit and push and have the binaries for Linux built on a machine running Jenkins (there already is an instance for building for Windows)

Seems like the built server part was the easier one since Jenkins provides an easy way to do that. For the Mono part there are quiet a lot dependencies and packages to choose from.

So I basically followed the [instructions for Jenkins provided at their side](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/) and Jenkins was running.

Now the question is what I need to install to get Jenkins build Mono projects. I'm working with Mono-Develop 3.0.4.7 at the moment and created a test console project. I'm not involving any third party libraries I guess but I don't really know what is contained in the Windows installation of Mono.

So this is what I'm asking for:

- What do I **need** to install on Ubuntu and what would be nice to have?
- Any special requirements for the project file? I read that Mono is using the Windows project format. Is that correct?
- Are there plugins for Jenkins supporting me with building for Mono?
- Anything I should take special care of? Like adding special paths to the PATH or certain tools that may be of interest?

Any sources of knowledge are of interest. I would be nice if they are explaining the **why**, I don't like reading "do this, then do that, and do another thing afterwards", without someone explaining the backgrounds, that much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> binaries for Linux built on a machine running Jenkins (there already is an instance for building for Windows)

If you have a build server on windows that is making your .NET assemblies then you don't need a linux one. Assemblies build with .NET 4.0 on Windows will run with the latest Mono runtime on linux without recompiling them. As long as you've ensured you don't use any of the missing API's from Mono. And if you are using the missing API's it won't compile with Mono anyways.

I suggest saving yourself the headache of manually building the Mono SDK on Ubuntu and keep with the Windows build server. Last time I checked you'd have to rebuild Mono on your Ubuntu system as the default install of Mono for Ubuntu is outdated.

Comment: mh, I guess I have to get back to the CLI schools to get my head around the characteristics of assemblies...

Thank you for your polite answer^^

Comment: @HaMster It is a portable format. You can even run the .exe files produced with .NET on Linux with the mono command line runtime.

Comment: I guess the problem was that I have always been playing on Windows Platforms when developing in C#, the portability is not that obvious there ;)

Comment: This is only true if you don't require any modifications to your code via #ifdefs when building on Mono vs .Net - which is quite common due to implementation differences in data structures.